# Await doesnt wait till a variable is set in an sync function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, apexcharts, data-uri

I am trying to get dataURI for an image using ApexCharts.exec method, here is my code:

```
const getDataURI = async() => {

  console.log('leftChartObj', leftChartObj) // gets the data required correctly - essentially an object which is used in the next line; so leftChartID is assigned the value as expected.

  const leftChartID = leftChartObj.props.options.chart.id;

  ApexCharts.exec(leftChartId, 'dataURI' , {scale:1.08}).then(  
  ( async ({imgURI}) => {
     await setSvgLeft(imgURI);          // These methods are inbuilt and I guess async/await isn't needed but I was just trying out.
 
     console.log('svgLeft', svgLeft) // state variable that is set in the above line =
  })
  );

  console.log('method ended', svgLeft) 

}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
leftChartObj { 'props': {...}, 'context': {...} , .. } - as expected

method ended null

svgLeft  null
```

I understand that the code is exiting before the variable is set, then tried async/await. But that didn't help either.

*Also, this function is called upon a button click in the UI, if the click the button for the second time everything works as expected.*

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `.then()`, it just makes your code confusing. Also, your comments are using the wrong slashes, should be `//`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, changed the question prompt.

Comment: You're still mixing `await` with `.then()`. I strongly suggest you completely avoid such a pattern

Comment: Is `setSvgLeft` a state setter? If so, this is a common mistake which can generally be solved by not relying on `console.log()` to test state

Answer (score 0):

In React's hook, you need to use `useEffect` to reach your prompt.
Something like this:

```
const getDataURI = async() => {

  const leftChartID = leftChartObj.props.options.chart.id;

  ApexCharts.exec(leftChartId, 'dataURI' , {scale:1.08}).then(  
  ( ({imgURI}) => {
     setSvgLeft(imgURI);
 
  })
  );

}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('svgLeft', svgLeft) // This line will run whenever `svgLeft` change
}, [svgLeft])
```

Comment: I do see the correct values when this useeffect is triggered, however, in the original method that called 'getDataURI' the required values are still 'null'.

So basically we are exiting the 'getDataURI' method before even reaching the place where is set the state variable.

Comment: As I told you. You cannot. You HAVE TO use `useEffect`, no other way to reach in `getDataURI`. You can use `imgURI` directly inside `getDataURI` instead of `svgLeft`